# Will the magnetism from a hard drive corrupt another hard drive while stacked(when not running)

Tags: hard-drive

I have some hard drives that are not being used anymore but I still have to use them sometimes do stacking the hard drives corrupt the data?

Answer (score 0):

No it won't corrupt the data. The magnetic fields from the magnets aren't big enough to affect other drives, specially since a drive has to work in proximity to the rest of the computer. It's external sources of magnetic fields you need to be concerned about because they could damage your drives

Comment: Would have to be one hell of a magnetic field

Comment: absolutely - a really strong magnet (with a pull force of at least 450 pounds, could harm a hard drive. - source(https://www.shredit.com/en-us/blog/cybersecurity/magnets-and-other-myths-hard-drive-destruction#:~:text=The%20expert%20reported%20that%20a,indeed%20harm%20a%20hard%20drive.)
I should add I don't think this will ever be an issue :)

Comment: I want a magnet that can pull 450!